# MySQL how to find percentage field population base on states in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I did some research but nothing seemed to help my individual case

I have a table (with 40 columns and million rows)

```
FirstName| LaseName | State |...100+ other columns|
aaa      | bbb      | CA
ccc      | ddd      | NY
abc      | null     | CA
null     | ggg      | AL
...150 million rows
```

I need a very long query to return something like below

```
State | field     | # of state pupulation | # of rows    in state | % state population
__________________________________________________________________________
AL    | firstName |  0                    |         1             | 0%
      | lastName  |  1                    |                       | 100%
__________________________________________________________________________
CA    | firstName |  2                    |         2             | 100%
      | lastname  |  1                    |                       | 50%
__________________________________________________________________________
NY    | firstName |  1                    |         1             | 100%
      | lastname  |  1                    |                       | 100%
```

this is for internal use only so format/order doesn't really matter as long as i can get the numbers needed

note that the % is calculated by (# of non null in state = AL, CA, etc / # of total records where state = AL, CA, etc)

and not (# of non null / # of all rows)

Im new to sql and I have no idea what to do

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :) Being new to SQL is not an excuse.

Comment: Millions of rows is fine, but 40 columns seems like a lot.

Comment: Write three subqueries. One subquery gets the total #rows for each state. One gets the count of non-null firstname for each state. One gets the count of non-null lastname for each state. Join the three subqueries and calculate the percentage of each from the total.

Comment: Hint: COUNT(columnname) will count only non-null values of that column.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need 3 subqueries, you can do all 3 counts in one query.

Comment: this is not a hw and i was just being told to finish this asap... @Barmar

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's homework or not, we don't do your work for you.

Comment: How did someone who doesn't know SQL end up with this job? Get the real database programmer to do it.

Comment: You just need to use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY state`. This is very simple SQL.

Comment: ok thanks ill see what i can come up with

Comment: im just a confused new grad have mercy

Comment: At first glance this looks like a pivot.

Comment: @Barmar My table is extremely large and takes 15 minutes to iterate from first row to last row. Is it viable for me to count the population & non null rows 50 times? will it result a run time of 15 min * 50 times just to do calculate the number of population in 50 states? i need to do it for a file with 300 columns...Will the then become 15 * 50 * 300 mins to complete running? or is mysql optimized somehow for that?

Comment: Performance will depend on the indexes you have on the columns. A composite index on `(state, firstname)` will help with this query.

Comment: from what i have heard there is no index on the table....

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible query pattern. To get the percentage, we divide the third expression in the select list by the fourth expression. (To do that in a single SELECT, we have to repeat those expressions, separated by the division operator.

```
SELECT c.state 

     , f.field

     , CASE f.field
       WHEN 'firstname'  THEN c.cnt_fn_nn
       WHEN 'lastname'   THEN c.cnt_ln_nn
       WHEN 'somecol'    THEN c.cnt_sc_nn
       ELSE NULL
       END        AS `# populated` 

     , c.cnt_tot  AS `# rows`

     , CASE f.field
       WHEN 'firstname'  THEN c.cnt_fn_nn
       WHEN 'lastname'   THEN c.cnt_ln_nn
       WHEN 'somecol'    THEN c.cnt_sc_nn
       ELSE NULL
       END
     / c.cnt_tot * 100.0 AS `pct`

  FROM ( SELECT 'firstname' AS `field`
          UNION ALL SELECT 'lastname'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'somecol'
       ) f
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT a.state
              , SUM(1) AS `cnt_tot`
              , SUM(a.first_name IS NOT NULL) AS `cnt_fn_nn`
              , SUM(a.last_name  IS NOT NULL) AS `cnt_ln_nn`
              , SUM(a.somecol    IS NOT NULL) AS `cnt_sc_nn`
           FROM atable a
          GROUP BY a.state
       ) c
 ORDER
    BY c.state
     , f.field
```

NOTES:

The inline view (derived table) `f` returns the `field` values we want to display in the second column.

The inline view (derived table) `c` gets us the "counts" by `state`.

The `GROUP BY` clause collapses all of the rows that have the same value for `state`, so we get one row back for each distinct value of `state`.

The expression  `a.first_name IS NOT NULL` is evaluated for each row, as a boolean, and returns either FALSE (0) or TRUE (1) for each row.  We can use the `SUM()` aggregate function to total up the ones and zeros. That gets us a count of the number of rows that have a non-null value for first_name.

`SUM(1)` will get us the same thing as `COUNT(*)` would. That's the total number of rows for each `state`.

We do a `CROSS JOIN` operation on the two inline views to produce a Cartesian (cross) product. Every row from `f` is matched to every row from `c`.  If we have 50 states, 50 rows from `c`, and three rows from `f`, that gets us a total of 50*3 rows.

The searched `CASE` expression is a SQL way of saying...

```
 if field = 'firstname'   then return cnt_fn_nn 
 elsif field = 'lastname' then return cnt_ln_nn
 ...
```

We use this to "pick out" the count we want to return on each row, return the count of first name not null on the row with `firstname` field.

This can be extended, copy the lines with `somecol` and replace that with a valid column name in `atable`, and assign a unique column alias `AS foo` to each expression in the SELECT list.

What this query doesn't get us is any `state` values that don't appear in `atable`. To get zero counts, we would need another source for `state`.

And this query doesn't suppress repeated values for state, or for `# rows in state`. Those values are returned on each row, even though they are duplicated.

To get those supressed would be icky, but we could do it.  To get it on the "first line" for each `state` we need to know which `field` is going to be first. We could do a conditional test in the first and fourth expressions in the SELECT list of the outer query.  Get the query working first, before you start mucking with it. (The suppression of repeated values would better be handled in the client that processes the result. But if the specification is to return that exact resultset, it can be done like this... I cringe...)

```
SELECT IF(f.field='firstname',c.state,'') AS `state` 

     , f.field

     , CASE f.field
       WHEN 'firstname'  THEN c.cnt_fn_nn
       WHEN 'lastname'   THEN c.cnt_ln_nn
       WHEN 'somecol'    THEN c.cnt_sc_nn
       ELSE NULL
       END        AS `# populated` 

     , IF(f.field='firstname',c.cnt_tot,NULL) AS `# rows`
```